# how to properly load a gcs file into gbq with double-pipe delimiters

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

my existing query:

```
bq load --field_delimiter="||" --skip_leading_rows=1 source.taxassessor gs://taxassessor/OFFRS_5_0_TAXASSESSOR_0001_001.txt taxassessor.txt
```

the error I get back is:

```
Not enough positional args, still looking for destination_table
```

I tried to mimic the command in the Web UI, and I cannot reproduce because the Web UI doesn't allow double-pipe delimiters (limitation on the UI? or the solution?)

I have two questions:

1. How do I repair the current query
2. the source file OFFRS_5_0_TAXASSESSOR_0001_001.txt is one of many source files with the last three characters of the file name showing what file number in the series that file is.  How do I use wild cards so I can get file 002.txt, 003.txt, etc.  something like OFFRS_5_0_TAXASSESSOR_0001_*.txt?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried placing the flags after the positional arguments? Also, I believe the `--field_delimiter` flag expects ***1 character***, but you have two pipes.

Comment: the problem is that my delimiter IS two pipes '||'.....what can I do?  Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any way you can change this without modifying the files locally (on your machine) and loading them to the table. You can use `cat` if the files are not too large. Otherwise you may have to use `cp` to copy them to our machine, make the modifications (replace `||` with `|` or `,`) and then load them to your table from your local machine.

Comment: Not sure about the two pipes but the error message is that you missed the destination_table positional arg. Although, looking at your command, you did provide it. This looks like a bug in the BigQuery command client. Please file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use wild cards so I can get file 002.txt, 003.txt, etc. something like OFFRS_5_0_TAXASSESSOR_0001_*.txt?

Do as you suggested, for instance:

```
bq load --field_delimiter="||" --skip_leading_rows=1 source.taxassessor gs://taxassessor/OFFRS_5_0_TAXASSESSOR_0001_*.txt taxassessor.txt
```

It should already work.

> How do I repair the current query?

Not sure why you are getting this message as everything seems to be correct...but still it shouldn't work as your delimiter have 2 characters and they are supposed to have just one (imagine for instance if your file has the string `"abcd|||efg||hijk|||l"`, it'd be hard to tell where the delimiter is; whether it's the first two pipes or the last).

If you can't change the delimiter, one thing you could do is saving everything in BigQuery as one entire `STRING` field. After that, you can extract the fields as you want, something like:

```
WITH data AS(
  select "alsdkfj||sldkjf" as field UNION ALL
  select "sldkfjld|||dlskfjdslk"
)

SELECT SPLIT(field, "||") all_fields FROM data
```

`all_fields` will have all columns in your files, you can then save the results to some other table or run any analyzes you want.

As a recommendation, it would probably be better if you could change this delimiter to something else, having just one character.